# SQL Server table view issue

Tags: .net, sql-server

Please check my table view. What happen with this. It is not showing design properly. Following is my SQL Server query:

```
SELECT Row_number()
        OVER (
            ORDER BY orderid) OAId,
        *
FROM (SELECT [branchoffice],
             [branchhabr],
             [ratingdesc],
             [deliveryappstatus],
             [cformdt]
      FROM branchorder
      WHERE [flag] in (1,2)
      UNION
      SELECT [branchoffice],
             [branchhabr],
             [ratingdesc],
             [cformdt]
      FROM branchorder12_13
      WHERE [flag] in (1,2)
      UNION
      SELECT [branchoffice],
             [branchhabr],
             [ratingdesc],
             [deliveryappstatus],
             [statename],
             [pulseenqid],
             [cformdt]
      FROM branchorder11_12
      WHERE [flag] in (1,2)) a
```

Comment: What is orderid? it is not part of derived table as I far as I see.

Comment: Use http://sqlfiddle.com/  to show your tables structures

Comment: "SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane." this error given by my table view. What is that and how can I solve it.

Comment: Can anyone tell me about * and how can I change it. I mean in above query the symbol * is show which table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**

If you use UNION

- The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all
  queries.
- The data types must be compatible.

But you make union with different number of columns.

**Second:**

If you use

`Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY orderid) OAId`

There must be a string in sub-query with name `orderid`

**Third:**

`*` means that all columns from query will be shown. You can remove `*` and list all columns what you needed.

So you get something like this:

```
SELECT Row_number()
        OVER (
            ORDER BY orderid) OAId,
        [branchoffice],
        [branchhabr],
        [ratingdesc],
        [deliveryappstatus],
        [statename],
        [pulseenqid],
        [cformdt],
        [orderid]
FROM (SELECT [branchoffice],
             [branchhabr],
             [ratingdesc],
             [deliveryappstatus],
             NULL as [statename],
             NULL as [pulseenqid],
             [cformdt],
             [orderid]
      FROM branchorder
      WHERE [flag] in (1,2)
      UNION
      SELECT [branchoffice],
             [branchhabr],
             [ratingdesc],
             NULL as [deliveryappstatus],
             NULL as [statename],
             NULL as [pulseenqid],
             [cformdt],
             [orderid]
      FROM branchorder12_13
      WHERE [flag] in (1,2)
      UNION
      SELECT [branchoffice],
             [branchhabr],
             [ratingdesc],
             [deliveryappstatus],
             [statename],
             [pulseenqid],
             [cformdt],
             [orderid]
      FROM branchorder11_12
      WHERE [flag] in (1,2)) a
```

Comment: can i send you my SQL Server query?

Comment: Yes, you can edit the post and add your current query.

Comment: I get it. It's not what you show in your question. What is it? Your view?

Comment: yes..its my view and that is shows only 7107 records while I have 9100 in my table which is named as "orderdetails".

Comment: Have you checked how many records do you get when choose from `dbo.OrderDetails where Flag IN (1, 2)`?

Comment: same 7107 only ....when I choose it from dbo.OrderDetails where Flag IN (1, 2) [just delete last line and run the query].

Comment: So, if you have 7107 records for `Flag IN (1, 2)`. It's all right that you got in your view 7107 records. It takes me to question, what is the problem?

Comment: See as I am discussed with you my table view query which is made for a report generation. The report has details of customer details (regarding there buy status). So, in this query I have only data till 2015. But I want 1 jan 2016 to till date data.. But I have not find the data from this query. it means the missing records of 2000 rows is that data. Which is I want.

Comment: Oh... what if: remove `Flag IN (1, 2)` from `WHERE` condition and change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: then it gives 7558 rows

Comment: You change ALL `inner` joins to `left`? It's strange that you don't get all rows from `orderdetails`.

Comment: Yes i am also surprise why not getting all rows .. And yes I change all inner to left. What I can do ?. :-(

Comment: And same this happen with my other table view.

Comment: Try at first select all you need from `orderdetails` then add first join and try once more, then next join and so step by step you will know where records are cut off.

Comment: ok dear.. I will check it. but can you check my one another view query please.

Comment: Also I reccomend to use syntax with pseudonyms like `FROM dbo.OrderDetails od INNER JOIN dbo.BranchMaster bm ON od.BranchId = bm.BranchID` it will make your code better to understand and read.